# FFTW 3.3.4 Windows Installation - cannot computer sizeof (size_t)

Tags: linux, sizeof, porting, fftw, size-t

I am attempting to compile FFTW on Windows 7. Per the [documentation guide](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html) on the official site, I am attempting to compile with the following line:

```
./configure --with-our-malloc16 --with-incoming-stack-boundary=2
```

It begins the configure process, and steps through okay until it reaches this point - where it causes an error that reads as such:

```
checking size of size_t... configure: error: in '/h/xcorrport/fftw-3.3.4': configure" error: cannot computer sizeof (size_t)
```

It logs this crash info to a config.log file, which I have included a link to [here](http://pastebin.com/7W54pwXY). Apologies for the length of this file, I am unsure which parts are most relevant to the question at hand.

I am working on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. FFTW also provides precompiled .DLL's, but I am unsure of how to install or use these.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It could be something simple, since the actual error is "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file conftest.exe"